# Why can't I install react-data-grid via npm?

Tags: node.js, github, reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I was trying to install the popular react components react-data-grid via npm

```
npm install --save react-data-grid
```

but I hit the following error:

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/rase-/node-XMLHttpRequest/archive/a6b6f2.tar.gz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error
```

I can download the .gz file directly when I paste the link onto my browser address bar.

can anyone help?

Comment: What is your node & npm version and OS ?

Comment: node-version:4.2.1, npm: 3.7.3, windows 7

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio on your machine?